# Плавное изменение opacity при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите пожалуйста сделать плавную прокрутку блоков как на tv3 (https://tv3.ru/) то есть изменение opacity в зависимости от высоты прокрутки.

Есть такой код html:

```
<style>
section {
height: 100vh;
}
</style>
<section>
//ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК
</section>
<section>
//ВТОРОЙ БЛОК
</section>
<section>
//ТРЕТИЙ БЛОК
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу для популяризации  stackoverflow , ответ откуда то от сюда

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
var elem = $(".section");
  var sTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  $(elem).each(function(i, el) { 
    var pTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var height = $(elem).height(); 

    var top = pTop - sTop + height; 
    if (top > 0) { 
      $(elem).css({
        opacity: function() {
          var elementHeight = $(elem).height();
          return 1 - top / 100 + height / 100;
        }
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body{height:1000px;}
.section{height:200px;width:100%;background-color:black;opacity:0.1;margin:100px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```